# Laravel 5.2 - Memcache with PHP7 - Class Memcache does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, memcached, php-7, pecl

I have recently upgraded the server to PHP7 (L5.2) and having trouble with Memcache. The error message is `Class Memcache does not exist`. I already have installed [Memcached PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached) but seems like it doesn't go well with PHP7. What is the best alternative solution to get it worked?

Comment: What is your host information? Operative System, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment I was installing memcached for PHP7 it was not finished as stable for PHP7. But here is the way to build it using commands:

```
yum install libmemcached-devel
wget https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/archive/php7.zip -O php-memcached-php7.zip
unzip php-memcached-php7.zip
cd php-memcached-php7
phpize
./configure
make
make install
echo 'extension=memcached.so' >> /etc/php.ini
```

This script is for CentOS 7, but generally it should work everywhere, with minor changes

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying the steps and getting the following error in Ubuntu 14.04. Can you please help me to understand what is going wrong here? `sudo yum install libmemcached-devel
There are no enabled repos.
 Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>

sudo yum install libmemcached-devel returned exit code 1

Action failed: sudo yum install libmemcached-devel`

Comment: It's because in Ubuntu another installer is in use: apt. For example:
sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev

Comment: My bad! I have done with the installation and everything went well. `extension=memcached.so` is added in the php.ini file. I am trying to use the class `Memcache` by it's namespace `use Memcache` but it says `unable to find class`. It is working fine in PHP5. It should work in the same way `Memcached PECL` works right?

Comment: Class name is Memcached, not Memcache. Use it as
$mem = new Memcached();
$mem->addServer("localhost", 11211);
$mem->add('your_key', 'your_value', 0);

Comment: I specifically wanted to use Memcache since I have Memcache class used with Laravel in my existing codebase. I could do this by building the package from https://github.com/websupport-sk/pecl-memcache. Thanks for getting me in the proper direction.

Answer (score 0):

For the other peeps who are coming across this question, I am posting the way I could do it. It may need some tweaks according to your environment but hoping this would help somebody. I am in Ubuntu 14.04.

```
  sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev
  wget https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/archive/php7.zip -O php-memcached-php7.zip
  unzip php-memcached-php7.zip
  cd php-memcached-php7 && phpize && ./configure --disable-memcached-sasl && make && sudo make install

  git clone https://github.com/websupport-sk/pecl-memcache.git
  cd pecl-memcache && phpize && ./configure --disable-memcache-sasl && make && sudo make install
  sudo echo 'extension=memcached.so' >> /path/to/php.ini
  sudo echo 'extension=memcache.so' >> /path/to/php.ini
```